Pyomo indexed set into constraint
I'm attempting to add an indexed set to a constraint, and Pyomo returns Cannot apply a Set operator to an indexed Set component (td)
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

td = {1:[1,2,3,5],2:[4]}

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.r = pyo.RangeSet(1,2)
model.t = pyo.RangeSet(1,5)

model.td_raw = pyo.Set(model.r,initialize=td)

def td_flat_rule(model):
    pairs = []
    for i in model.td_raw:
        for j in model.td_raw[i]:
            pairs.append((i,j))
    # print(pairs)
    return pairs
model.td = pyo.Set(td_flat_rule,dimen=2)
model.PD = pyo.Var(model.r, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

def PD_constraint_rule(model,i,r):
    return (model.PD[(r for (r,i) in model.td)] >= model.TG[i])

model.AxbConstraint = pyo.Constraint(model.td, rule=PD_constraint_rule)

opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
results = opt.solve(model)
results.write()

The model.pprint() output just prior to the constraint:
2 Set Declarations
    td : Size=0, Index={(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 4)}, Ordered=Insertion
        Key : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
    td_raw : Size=2, Index=r, Ordered=Insertion
        Key : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
          1 :     1 :    Any :    4 : {1, 2, 3, 5}
          2 :     1 :    Any :    1 : {4,}

2 RangeSet Declarations
    r : Dimen=1, Size=2, Bounds=(1, 2)
        Key  : Finite : Members
        None :   True :   [1:2]
    t : Dimen=1, Size=5, Bounds=(1, 5)
        Key  : Finite : Members
        None :   True :   [1:5]

1 Var Declarations
    PD : Size=2, Index=r
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          1 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
          2 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

5 Declarations: r t td_raw td PD

I found somewhere that a set of sets (model.td_raw) needs to flattened to an explicit set of tuples, thus the td_flat_rule. I also found something saying that a reverse map of model.td might be the solution for the constraint, but I'm unsure of how to accomplish that.  I'm almost positive that the constraint rule is wrong.

This question is similar to: Pyomo create a constraint based on an indexed set. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

comment back if that link doesn't answer your question.  it shows several ways to work with indexed sets.

Thank you @AirSquid.  That looks like it might be the answer, however, if I simply replace the graph dict in the example with the dict in my code block({1:[1,2,3,5],2:[4]}), Pyomo returns ValueError: Cannot add value 3 to Set C[1]. The value is not in the domain N

And the same if I comment out m.C and move on to m.NN.  If it helps, in my model, r is unique windows of time and t are timesteps within those windows

Well, sure.  it's an example of a structure.  Your dictionary td does not define 3 as a key or node.

I think one of the sources of my issue is that the values in td are timesteps that are used for other elements in the model and the struggle is associating the values with the keys which are windows of time so the constraint is referencing the same iterable
